# PHP: getting 1 instead of 0 using count()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, backend

I'm adding a view counter to my website.
In the code, I check if there's an IP with the id of the post.

for example when post id is 26, and there's no IP with id 26 in my IP table, it should return 0 but it returns 1 instead.

```
  $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $checkIp = $db->prepare("SELECT user_ip FROM user_ip WHERE word_id = '$idToShow'");
  $checkIp->execute();
//This happens
  if (count($checkIp) > 0) {
    echo count($checkIp);
    echo " ". $idToShow;
  }
//instead of this
  else {
    $insertIP = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_ip (user_ip, word_id) values('$userIp', '$idToShow')");
    $insertIP->execute();
    $updateView = $db->prepare("UPDATE words set views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$idToShow'");
    $updateView->execute();
  }
```

Comment: what is the value of $idToShow

Comment: I have a list of words, $idToShow is the id of the word that should be showing. (for example 26)@RAUSHANKUMAR

Comment: Isn't `$checkIp` your PDOStatement object or similar? At least it isn't a result set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execute()` method runs the query returns a boolean value for if the query successful or not. 
You can use `rowsCount()` to count the rows or you can `fetchAll()` and then count the results.

You should use something like this

```
$checkIp->execute();
if ($checkIp && $checkIp->rowsCount() > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

**OR**

```
$checkIp->execute();
$ips = $checkIp->fetchAll();
if (count($ips) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using PDO

Here you are using prepared statements for querying database, but you are not fetching the result that has been returned by a database

use

```
$result = $checkIp->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($result) > 0){
  .............
}
else{
  ..........
}
```

Even simpler you can use

```
$checkIp->rowCount()
```

this returns number of rows effected by your query

Answer (score 2):

`$checkIp->execute();` is always returns boolean value, so your condition is wrong here. check the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php use like this

```
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$checkIp = $db->prepare("SELECT user_ip FROM user_ip WHERE word_id = '$idToShow'");
$result=$checkIp->execute();
if (!$result) {
    echo count($checkIp);
    echo " ". $idToShow;
}else {
    $insertIP = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_ip (user_ip, word_id) values('$userIp', '$idToShow')");
    $insertIP->execute();
    $updateView = $db->prepare("UPDATE words set views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$idToShow'");
    $updateView->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
if (count($checkIp) > 0)
```

Use

```
if(isset($checkIp->user_ip) && !empty($checkIp->user_ip))
```

Answer (score 1):

As in PHP doc the execute retunr TRUE or False

```
$checkIp->execute();
```

so your

```
(count($checkIp)
```

just count the var content  that in this case contai just a value

Answer (score 1):

`$checkIp` is an object and will always (assuming your prepare was successful) return a non-zero count. What you want (assuming you are using `mysqli`) is `$checkIp->num_rows`. If you are using `PDO`, you want `$checkIp->rowCount()`.